# Can't "combine" two variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a very simple ammo script in the game engine called **Unity**.

**C#**:

```
public int ammoCount = 30;
public string ammoText;

void magazine()
{
    ammoText = "AMMO " + ammoCount + "/30";

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        ammoCount = - 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        ammoCount = 30;
    }
}
```

So the thing I want you to focus on is the "ammoText = "AMMO " + ammoCountString + "/30";".
I've searched around on google, and as I see it, it is as it should be.

Further down in my code I wrote some code to make the variable appear onscreen, but it only shows "AMMO".

Any answers out there?

Thanks in forward.

-Mads

EDIT: It seems that it's not my script. Sorry guys! But maybe you know why it won't show my variable?

Code to show variable on screen: GUI.Label (new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), (ammoText));

Comment: I don't understand. What is the value of `ammoCountString` ?

Comment: Oh sorry! That was something i tried before! Changing it now :)

Comment: Post code where you print the ammoText variable, and other related code.

Comment: I've edited your question, see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think it's the script. I just found out that if i change the varibles in the unity interface, that's what appears. http://gyazo.com/df5cea33528d2c4cf4147d1ddf9ec8f6

Comment: you could also go for a ammoText = string.Format("AMMO {0}/30", ammoCount);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script seems a little awkward - not fully sure how its being called or how you're outputting it to the screen. Is this a method in a MonoBehaviour?

You can output debug information to the Unity console by writing Debug.WriteLine("Some text or a variable"), which will help you figure out what's going on.

Aside from the fact the code is a bit verbose, I see no problem with what you're trying to do, though I'm not sure why you'd want a value of -1 or 30, with nothing in between. Are you trying to remove 1 ammo from the clip when you press Mouse0? If so, use the code I've posted below. I've also "improved" the code a bit, to give you a bit more control. Some of your variables should be private (though I'm not 100% sure which ones in your case) as there's no benefit to accessing them via the Unity Editor.

Though your code will work, when I'm concatenating in C# I tend to use string.Concat() or string.Format(), as they makes things a bit neater, and they're slightly more efficient (which is another topic entirely).

```
public int ammoInFullClip = 30;
private int currentAmmoCount = 30;
private string ammoText;

void magazine()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        currentAmmoCount-= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        currentAmmoCount= ammoInFullClip;
    }

    ammoText = string.Format("AMMO {0}/{1}", currentAmmoCount, ammoInFullClip);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using your code, here's a full example that *should* work, though I haven't tested it.

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public int ammoInFullClip = 30;
    private int currentAmmoCount = 30;
    private string ammoText;

    private void UpdateMagazine() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) {
            currentAmmoCount -= 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R)) {
            currentAmmoCount = ammoInFullClip;
        }

        ammoText = string.Format("AMMO {0}/{1}", currentAmmoCount, ammoInFullClip);
    }

    public void Update() {
        UpdateMagazine();
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        Debug.WriteLine(ammoText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Yes, i was trying to remove 1 ammo for every shot. Oh, and read my EDIT. It makes my original question irrelevant, but if any of you guys know that kind of problem, please feel free to answer on that one too.

Comment: Not really - by the sounds of it, you're confusing how the unity editor uses variables. Rather, how c# variable scope works. I've updated my answer with a bit more info. You need to protect local variables by making them private etc.

Comment: Yeah, i was :) I kinda figured it out just as you wrote this :P 2 Questions. One: Why did you make ammoInFullClip public, instead of private as the other ones? Two: Wouldn't private make them inaccesible for the void magazine?   You must understand that I've not a skilled programmer, so I don't really understand coding that much. (As you might have guessed ;) )  Thanks!

Comment: ammoInFullClip is public so it can be configured via the editor - that way, when you apply this monobehavior to different game objects, you can configure clip sizes per object (or you can change it for the current object without modifying any code). I mean... it would make sense to create some kind of gun object and apply the ammoInFullClip to that instead, but that's another subject altogether :)

Comment: Personally, I would be putting Debug.Write statements all over so you can trace the output. It sounds like you're either calling the script in the wrong place, or your overwriting the ammoText variable elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, i tried adding one to the ammoText variable, but that doesn't even show up. Wierd.

Comment: Where are you outputting ammoText? I assume it's inside OnGUI()?

Comment: It is, yeah. It doesn't even output my "Test", so I'll see what's wrong. Hold on.

Comment: Alright, i got it to output it. Null is the value of ammoText

Comment: Ey! I wrote magazine(); in the OnGUI, and now it works as it should! Is that wrong, or is that right to do?

Comment: You should not call magazine() from OnGUI really - because it does more than GUI based operations. You should call it from Update(), then reference the variable in OnGUI.

Comment: Already changed that. That's it! You resolved the question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate a string and an int, if the number is after a string, you don't need to user ToString, simply use :

```
ammoText = "AMMO " + ammoCount + "/30";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare variables as public just you can declare as below

int ammoCount = 30;
 string ammoText;

Your concatenation will work without any problem.